# Android layout, specify dp to scale with screen size

Tags: android, layout

I've been trying to get a universal layout working on Android with no success. My understanding is that if you specify all widgets in dp, and make it look right in one screen size, it should scale properly to other resolutions, but my results look kinda wrong to me.

I layed out everything in HVGA using a relative layout. The relative layout has a background that our UI designer used to define element boundaries. In this layout, everything looks perfect.

Then I switch to a larger screen with a slightly different aspect ratios, the background scales properly but everything else looks off by some dp. My question is, what is the golden way to make all the elements scale correctly with screen. I want to preserve the ratios of all the elements with respect to the background. 
[image: Layout where everything looks fine]

[image: scaled up layout where background looks fine but the left listview with a 100dp width scales improperly]

Thanks!

Edit: figured out how to do this. The reason for inconsistency between buttons and background is that background is scaled differently from dp, and devices apparently have different dps. The solution is to manually compute the scale factor from absolute pixels then scale everything manually by that factor.  Here is a good reference how to do this: 
[Scale Android for different screens](http://www.vanteon.com/downloads/Vanteon_Android_White_Paper.pdf)

Comment: adding a screenshot would help us see what you mean (what the problem is)

Comment: Just got enough reputation. Screenshots uploaded. :D

Comment: Original post updated to show my solution.

Answer (score 2):

dp scales itself in such a manner so that the size of any widget remains constant on different  screens having different resolution.
In your case, the size of list-view remains constant but the background stretched to the screen width. To avoid this, use first colour as background of first list-view and same as for second list-view.